# Long text string wrapping in a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, booktabs, wrap

I am currently trying to create a simple 4-column table and I've been trying to sort out the wrapping issue.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{- Main silicate HFSE-hosting minerals from major ore deposits}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.1\textwidth}m{0.4\textwidth}m{0.3\textwidth}m{0.2\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        Mineral&Formula&HFSE-hosting sites&Ref.\\
        \midrule
        allanite (epidote) & $A_{2}M_{3}Si_{3}O_{12}[OH]$ & A = REE$^{3+}$; B = U$^{4+}$, Th$^{4+}$, Zr$^{4+}$ & citation\\
        chevkinite & $A_{4}BC_{2}D_{2}(Si_{2}O_{7})_{2}O_{8}$ & A = REE$^{3+}$; B = Zr$^{4+}$, Ti$^{4+}$; C = Ti$^{4+}$, Nb$^{5+}$ & citation\\
        eudialyte & $N_{15-16}[M1]_{6}[M2]_{3}[M3][M4]Z_{3}Si_{24}O_{66-73}(W)_{0-9}(X)_{2}$ & N \& M1 = REE$^{3+}$; M2 = Zr$^{4}$, Ta$^{5+}$, Ti$^{4+}$; M3/4 = Nb$^{5+}$, Ti$^{4+}$; Z = Zr$^{4+}$, Ti$^{4+}$, Nb$^{5+}$ & citation\\
                
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

producing this

[image]

2 questions (apologies, I realise it's supposed to deal with 1 issue at a time):
a) how can I make the long-string in the 2nd column wrap down according to the column width?
b) what needs to change in the caption setup to separate the number from the caption text? at the moment I've put in the hyphen trying to circumvent it, but obviously LaTeX ignores spaces

Comment: It's impossible to answer the second question without knowing your setup.

Comment: Do please share with us some pertinent pieces of information, such as the document class that's in use, which fonts you employ, and how wide the text block is.

Comment: While it doesn't answer either question, you should look at the chemformula package.

Comment: My apologies.
Document class is a custom thesis template after overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-reports-from-agh/qftddmhknmpw, which I've tailored for my PhD. I believe root is a report class. How could I clarify fonts?
Not 100% on how big the text block is, but the page is a4 paper with the following margins:
```\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=25mm, bmargin=25mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, I suggest you employ judiciously chosen `\newline` directives. Regarding your second question, I suggest you load the `caption` package and employ a suitable value for the `labelsep` option.

Whatever else you do, though, I strongly recommend you load one of several possible chemical formula packages and use their macros to typeset chemical compounds. For sure, I would hope that you'll agree that the output of `\ce{A2M3Si3O12[OH]}` is a lot better-looking than that of `$A_{2}M_{3}Si_{3}O_{12}[OH]$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} % I don't have access to your custom LaTeX class
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, vmargin=25mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}} % automatic hanging indentations
\usepackage{mhchem} % provides \ce macro to typeset chemical formulas
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip,labelfont=sc,labelsep=endash]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Main silicate HFSE-hosting minerals from major ore deposits}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} 
   >{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr0.12\textwidth-1\tabcolsep\relax}
   P{\dimexpr0.40\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
   P{\dimexpr0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
   P{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-1\tabcolsep\relax} 
     @{} }
\toprule
Mineral & Formula & HFSE-hosting sites & Ref.\\
\midrule
allanite (epidote) 
  & \ce{A2M3Si3O12[OH]} 
  & A = \ce{REE^3+}; B = \ce{U^4+}, \ce{Th^4+}, \ce{Zr^4+} 
  & citation\\
chevkinite 
  & \ce{A4BC2D2(Si2O7)2O8}  
  & A = \ce{REE^3+}; B = \ce{Zr^4+}, \ce{Ti^4+}; C = \ce{Ti^4+}, \ce{Nb^5+} 
  & citation\\
eudialyte 
  & \ce{N_{15-16}[M{1}]6[M{2}]3[M{3}][M{4}]Z3Si24\newline O_{66-73}(W)_{0-9}(X)2}
  & N \& M1 = \ce{REE^3+}; M2 = \ce{Zr^4+}, \ce{Ta^5+}, \ce{Ti^4+}; 
    M3/4 = \ce{Nb^5+}, \ce{Ti^4+}; Z = \ce{Zr^4+}, \ce{Ti^4+}, \ce{Nb^5+}
  & citation\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks a lovely solution. I certainly do agree about the chemical formula package. Many thanks!